# Batch File script to update a file

Tags: c, batch-file, cmd, system

I have a file named "test.txt" in desktop.

Content of the File is as follow

<op>1</op>
<sub>12</sub>

Now I have to write a bat file which read <sub> value and increment it by 1 and then save the file.
Result:
<sub>13</sub>

Please help me on creating a batch for the same.

Can I achieve the same in C programing. If yes then please let me know how.

Comment: `Can I achieve the same in C programing?`, Yes, you can, use `fgets`, `strcmp` and `fprintf`

Comment: Where is you current version of the code? Show us your efforts!

Comment: I need to save the file too.

Comment: @VishalSrivastava, `fopen("test.txt", "r+");`, open a file for update (both for input and output).

Comment: can u please provide the code for the same

Comment: @VishalSrivastava People tend not to like the "Plz give teh codes". You need to provide an [example of what you've done](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

sample by powershell

```
$str = Get-Content "test.txt"
$xml = [xml]("<root>" + $str + "</root>")
$xml.root.sub = [String]([Int]$xml.root.sub + 1)
$xml.root.InnerXml | Out-File -FilePath "test.txt" -Encoding ASCII
```